# Google Apps ScriptでDropboxのファイルを取得したい。

Tags: google-apps-script, dropbox

Google Apps ScripでDropboxのファイル一覧を取得し、Spreadsheetに挿入したいです。
Dropbox APIのHTTPリクエストとして以下を用いましたが、
エラーが返ってきてしまいます。
bodyの内容がJSONじゃないと言われているようです。
どこに問題があるでしょうか。

```
return UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder",
    {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "method" : "post",
      "headers" : {
        "Authorization" : "Bearer (TOKEN)",
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
      },
      "body" : {
        "path" : ""
      },
      "muteHttpExceptions" : false
    }
  );
```

`Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": request body: could not decode input as JSON`

Answer (score 1):

[Dropbox の API リファレンス](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)を見たところ HTTP リクエストの本体にJSON文字列を指定するのだと思うので以下のように文字列化して渡すのではないでしょうか？ お試しください。

```
return UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder",
    {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "method" : "post",
      "headers" : {
        "Authorization" : "Bearer (TOKEN)",
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
      },
      // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
      'payload' : JSON.stringify({
        "path" : ""
      }),
      "muteHttpExceptions" : false
    }
  );
```